# Excel Reader C# reading in extra line

Tags: c#, import-from-excel

```
 private bool CompetitorParseFile(Stream file, int competitorId)
    {
        var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(file);

        var accounts = new List<CreateEditAccountModel>();
        var _line = 1;

        while (excelReader.Read())
        {
            if (_line == 1)
            {
                _line++;
                continue;
            }
            var accountName = excelReader.GetString(0);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accountName))
            {
                throw new Exception("The Account Name shouldn't be null on line " + _line + " of the Excel Sheet");
            }

            var subsidiaryName = excelReader.GetString(1);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subsidiaryName))
            {
                throw new Exception("The Subsidiary Name shouldn't be null on line " + _line + " of the Excel Sheet");
            }

            var subsidiary = Db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(i => i.CompanyCodeName == subsidiaryName);
            if (subsidiary == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("The subsidiary couldn't be found");
            }

            var subsidiaryId = subsidiary.ID;


            accounts.Add(new CreateEditAccountModel
            {
                AccountName = excelReader.GetString(0) == null ? null : excelReader.GetString(0).Trim(),
                SubsidiaryId = subsidiaryId,
                Keywords = excelReader.GetString(2) == null ? null : excelReader.GetString(2).Trim()
            });
            _line++;
        }
        excelReader.Close();


        if (competitorId == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("The Competitor ID name shouldn't be null");
        }



        InitializeUserImporting(ImportOrigin.EntityWithCompetitors);
        ImportCompetitorFromExcel(new ImportEntities { competitorId = competitorId, Entities = accounts });

        return true;

    }
```

My excel reader is reading in one line too many and throwing the exception "The account name shouldn't be null"
The excel reader skips the first line as these are column names. 
Any help appreciated the excel file is an .xlsx file.

Comment: Its a problem I've found with Excel files, there always seems to be a blank row at the end of the file. I would just check if all the values are null consider it the end of the file or at least just skip it.

Comment: 1. Select and `Delete` or `Clear Contents` from the EXCEL file

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky I can't clear contents because this is being used by a lot of people. So if one person has an empty cell in their spread sheet it will thrown the error.

Comment: @user3922757 another option is to put some kind of marker in the last row. I believe there might be rows with null account numbers, so you cannot check for `null` and terminate thinking its the end...

Comment: I just got a screen shot and the person uploaded the wrong excel template.